# Adding jQuery to Seattle masterpage

Tags: master-page, sharepoint-on-prem, scriptlink

I'm trying to add jquery to my Seattle masterpage. I followed [these directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305168/how-to-add-jquery-to-masterpage-2013) which say to add the following (modified for my locations) line to the Seattle.html file.

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="'~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/custom/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" runat="server" Localizable="false" />-->
```

I added that line right after the other ScriptLinks that were already there. I then load the page back up and I get the "Something went wrong error" when I try and load any page (all the admin ones) that uses it.

Is that the wrong location to add that line?

How can I add jquery to my Seattle masterpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier than modifiyng the MasterPage:

Use the Chrome Extension SharePoint Editor **once**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd?hl=en

to load jQuery with a UserCustomAction ScriptLink

That will load jQuery early on on **every** page in the SiteCollection

Comment: That looks like it is for SP online? I should have specified that we have 2013 on prem.

Comment: UserCustomActions have been around since SP2010, never tried it but that extension should work on all environments, if not check John Lui's blog on UserCustomActions

Comment: I couldn't get the extension to do anything, but John Liu's blog worked!

Answer (score 0):

An alternate method is to add the `<script>` tag directly in `<head>` section in master page as the following:

- Upload your js file to `Asset Library` or `Style Library` in SharePoint site collection.
- Open SharePoint Designer > Go to Master Page > Right click on your custom master page HTML file and Check it out.
- Right click -> Edit in advanced mode.
- In **< head >** section add your reference of your js file like `<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Style Library/JS/jquery7.min.js">`

**Note:** To get the correct URL > write Src=" > then the `Pick URL` button should be shown, navigate to your js file in Style Library.

- Save -> Right click Check-in -> Publish As Major version ->

[image]

- This is will open your master page gallery -> right click and select publish.

[image]

Alternatively, you can use delegate control as mentioned at [Adding jQuery to Every Page in SharePoint with Delegate Controls](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2011/04/06/adding-jquery-to-every-page-in-sharepoint-with-delegate-controls/)